# OS X - Using printf in bash with Unicode characters does not render some characters

Tags: bash, unicode

I've created a script that will print out a range of Unicode characters. Some of the more exotic characters are not working. Specifically trying to make the [Latin Extended-D](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA720.pdf) characters work. I've tried using the Cardo font, but that did not help. I guess I can only post 2 links at a time so can't give that link. Any help appreciated. Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

COUNT=0

for i in $( seq $1 $2);
do
    x=$( printf "%X" "$i" );
    printf "\U$x";
    COUNT=$((COUNT+1));
    if [ $COUNT -gt $3 ]
        then
            COUNT=0;
            printf "\n";
    fi
done

printf "\n"
```

Here's what the terminal looks like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbdp6.png)

Comment: Which characters are missing? The Latin Extended-D block contains a large section of unassigned characters.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, these characters are "not working" in the terminal because they don't exist! Unicode characters U+A7AE, U+A7AF, and U+A7B8–A7F6 (in decimal: 42926, 42927, and 42936–42998) have not yet been defined by the Unicode Consortium, so they have no printable form. (They correspond to the crosshatched boxes on the second page of the PDF you linked.)

Answer (score 0):

This code prints a table similar to the one from UNICODE consortium:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

set   -- 42784 43007
for   j in {0..15};
do
      for   (( i=$1; i<=$2; i+=16 ));
      do
            k="$((i+j))"
            #printf '%4x ' "$k"
            printf "%b" $( printf '\\U0%x' "$k" );
      done
      printf "\n"
done
```

But there is no way to "see" all the code points because many code points do not have a glyph yet (A788-A7F6).
In other words: The code point (number) still does not have a character assigned.
It does not matter which font you choose, no font should have characters in those code points (A788-A7F6).